# I am getting this type of array when i try to push object into an array in jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays

while inspecting in browser, I am getting this type of array and I am unable to access 0th index of array.

```
function xyz()
{
var obj={
name: "abc",
age: "20"


var VArr=[];
VArr.push(obj);
}
```

> ```
> []
> 0:Array(1)
> 0:{name:"abc",age:"20"}
> ```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am unable to acces it?"

Comment: Yeah as above, what do you mean by "I am unable to acces it"? And where are you getting it from? Did it just fall there? Where are you trying to log the contents of the array?

Comment: Nothing in your code _"outputs"_ anything. Please explain the problem clearly and describe what you expect to see / happen vs what is actually happening

Comment: @Programnik i mena that i am unable to access the 0th index of array..

Comment: Where is your code that is trying to access the array?

Comment: @Phil i am try this code in a function

Comment: @mihirprajapati Please reread [ask], and especially how to make a [mcve]

Comment: @mihirprajapati you can check which i posted.

Comment: _"i am try this code in a function"_  this is entirely unhelpful. Please add all relevant code to your question

Comment: @Phil I have edited question  for you above..

Comment: No you have not. I'll ask again... Where is your code that is trying to access the array?

Answer (score 0):

First acess to the array by `VArr[0]` inside this u have your objecet to access your object property use dot notation like this

```
console.log(VArr[0].name)
```

Full code

```
function xyz(){
    var obj={
       name: "abc",
       age: "20"
    }

    var VArr=[];
    VArr.push(obj);
    console.log(VArr[0].name)
}
xyz()
```